# Performing a segue after animation is finished

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to perform a segue after an animation is finished. Here is the code I have in viewDidAppear:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    imageViewAnimated.startAnimating()


    if label.center != CGPoint(x:50, y:10) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.label.center = self.view.center

            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            //                self.label.center = CGPoint(x: 50,y:300)
            self.label.alpha = 0.0

            }, completion: nil)
    }

    if label.alpha == 0.0 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 10.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: self)

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So basically I have a label that's moving down and fading out(the first and second animateWithDuration), and then I want the Segue to occur after the label is faded out and the other animation is done. Right now the segue is happening, but it does it right away and doesn't wait no matter how much I increase the delay.

Comment: If you want to perform any action after a function gets completed, then you have to code it on "Completion" block. A completion block will get called after the method finishes its work.

Comment: I have updated the answer just check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the segue in the wrong place. You want something like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    imageViewAnimated.startAnimating()

    if label.center != CGPoint(x:50, y:10) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.label.center = self.view.center
        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            //                self.label.center = CGPoint(x: 50,y:300)
            self.label.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: self)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I'm not sure why but it's taking awhile (about 15 seconds to do the segue). It could just be my slow computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Run your segue code after completion. you have to code it on "Completion" block. A completion block will get called after the method finishes animation**

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 10.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

               //if you perform segue here if will perform with animation

                }, completion: { finished in

      //if you perform segue it will perform after it finish animating.

     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: self)


    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the navigation code in the completion handler part of animation block, because that completion handler will fire after the completion of animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    //Animation changes
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Navigation
}];
```

Comment: Note that the question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C.